# Planck constant in geometrized units?

Tags: definition, units, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, absolute-units

How do I calculate the value of the Planck constant in geometrized units?

I cannot find its value anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy details of the method can be found  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system).

$$E=h\nu=\frac{hc}{\lambda}\Rightarrow h=\frac{E\lambda}{c}$$
In  geometric units $c=1$, length =$[L]$ and energy $[L]$ so the geometric unit of planck constant is $1=[L^2]$.

---

To find the value, We need to find out the multiplier so :

The multiplier for length: $1$, for energy $Gc^{-4}$ and
$c$ is the velocity for which the multiplier is $c^{-1}$. Thus for the $h$, we have $Gc^{-3}$. So you just need to multiply this value to the value of $h$ in SI units that I leave to you.

Comment: I am sorry maybe a wasn't clear: I meant its **value** not its units

Comment: Pardon me, Is it okay now?

Comment: Thanks it is clear now.

Comment: This is wrong. The multiplication factor is $Gc^{-3}$, not $Gc^{-4}$. Look at the entry in the Wikipedia table for angular momentum.

Comment: @G.Smith Sorry I didn't take $c$ into account, I corrected it now. Thanks !